# Pushing edited data to array returning original data in forEach loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, foreach

I'm trying to read an .html document using node, creating an array with said document, then attempting to iterate thru the array to look for placeholders that are in the document to swap data from an object that was created from a .csv read file.

When I console.log the array after running, it shows the information as though it's never been edited with the forEach loop. Am I missing something with async code?

**Here it is:**

```
import * as fs from 'node:fs';
import { parse } from 'csv-parse';
 

fs.readFile('test.csv', 'utf8', (err, data) => {
        let matrix = [];
        if (err) throw err;

        parse(data, {columns: true, trim: true}, function(err, rows) {
            if (err) throw err;
            rows.forEach(row => {
                // console.log(row)

                const newCode = []
                for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(row)) {
                    // console.log(key)

                    const keyToSearch = `{(${key})}`

                    try {
                        const data = fs.readFileSync('index.html', 'utf8')
                        const dataArr = data.split('\n')
                        
                        
                        dataArr.forEach(line => {
                            if (!line.includes(keyToSearch)) {
                                newCode.push(line)
                            } else {
                                let newLine = line.replace(keyToSearch, value)
                                newCode.push(newLine)
                            }
                        })
                        
                    }catch(err) {
                        console.error(err)
                    }
                    
                    
                }
                console.log(newCode)


                

            })
        })

    })
```

Comment: 1. you keep reading the same file over and over again 2. you can run replace() on a string that doesn't contain the search term without issue 3. to change an array to a new array, don't use forEach() but map()

Comment: Also I'm reasonably sure that there's no need to split up the file into lines. If you create a regular expression based on your keyword (google how to insert a string var into a regexp) you only need a single .replace() call for each `key`.

Comment: Thank you for your information - I was able to rethink the code and get it do what I had hoped with your tips!